# Unexpected require in my config/application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue with the following line in the `config/application.rb` file of my generated `spec/dummy` rails application:

```
# railtie requires ...

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
require "tm_app_core" # This line should not exists according to rails application.rb template

module Dummy
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
```

I am using `Rails::Generators::AppGenerator` to generate my dummy app. But according to [Rails application.rb template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/application.rb#L14-L21) it should not have the following line:

```
require "tm_app_core"
```

**Where does this line comes from?**

I'm using Rails 3.2.13. `tm_app_core` is the name of my root directory (will be different on my CI server for example).